# Push MYSQL table onto another PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html-table, session-variables

I have two PHP pages. On page1 a temporary table is created and filled with data from a mysql database. I am trying to store this table into a `$_SESSION` variable so that I can put the table onto page2.

Right now this has been my approach:

This is the code on page1:

```
//Select data from database
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM table");
//Set array
$array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // add each row returned into an array
  $array[] = $row;
}

//store array into session variable
$_SESSION['fase1result'] = $array;
```

This is the code on page2:

```
$table = $_SESSION['fase1result'];

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ProductID</th>
<th>ProductName</th>
<th>Fase1</th>
</tr>";

foreach ($table as $row)
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ProductID'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ProductName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Fase1'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Unfortunately, up until now these scripts return me an empty table on page2. Help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
Best thing for me would be to preserve the temporary table as is, so that I'm able to further manipulate it with MySQL queries on page 2. Do you know how to do that instead of ripping it apart by pulling the data into a php array? Sorry for mixing up this question a little bit.

Comment: do you have `session_start()` at the top of both pages?

Comment: Why would you not just query the database again?

Comment: May not be a real reason but are you using session_start?

Comment: @MikeBrant You can indeed dump an array into a PHP session just like that and PHP will do the right thing. PHP handles whatever serialization is necessary to store the session in whatever underlying persistence layer. Why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: I am using session_start() at the top of both pages. Querying the database is not really an option (I think) because it is a temporary table that is created on page 1.

Comment: Are you sure that the array is actually being filled? `var_dump($array);` on page1

Comment: why wouldn't it be an option? you're pulling the results from the db, stashing the results in the session and then retrieving them again in another page. I don't think you're fully explaining as this is pointless as it stands

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`session_start()`](http://www.php.net/function.session-start) before using any session-related facilities.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['fase1result'] = $array;
```

then

```
session_start();
$table = $_SESSION['fase1result'];
```

Note that in most cases you need to call `session_start()` before any output, since it typically needs to send `Cookie:` headers to the client browser unless you have configured a different means of session persistence. Failing to do so can result in "header already sent" errors.

Comment: that's more of a comment, and if you really want to make it as an answer, you should add more details... adding `session_start();` after output could cause issues...

Comment: @CodeBird Whether `session_start()` has to happen before any output depends on the persistence layer used for sessions.

Comment: better now.... Thanks. But your answer doesn't stand anymore as the OP said in his comment that he is using session_start

Answer (score 0):

As tgies already pointed out, you need to have your session intialized.

Furthermore you use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` eventhough you're using mysqli (at least for the query), use `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` or the`mysqli_fetch_assoc` function (note the i).

Edit: There are several other options, but in most cases storing the data in a single, persistent table and identify it via an id in $_SESSION is a good way.

Comment: Also use the pdo or mysqli libraries as just the mysql library is insecure and also deprecated

Comment: He's using mysqli_query, therefore the error could be caused by this function call as it expects a mysql-result.

Comment: good eye @Sebb, I think that's actually the issue. You should be updating your answer at the place of commenting on it

Comment: So how can I store the data in a single table? Could I just do:
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM table");
And then:
$_SESSION['fase1result'] = $result;
And on the following page call the table by using this $_SESSION variable?

Comment: Hard to say because I don't know what your table actually does, but for this approuch you'd have to add two rows: One with an unique id (gerated via `uniqid()` or `md5(session_id())`) and one with a timestamp, then you store the id in $_SESSION and in the next page you use `$db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE unique_id=".$_SESSION["myid"]);`. At the top of Script 1 or via cronjob you should then delete all entries older than 5 min or so.